# i cant run php artisan make:controller FallbackController

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-9, fallback

It gives me this error

**ArgumentCountError**

**Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::fallback(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmvcc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 338 and exactly 1 expected**

im using laravel 9.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: You've to give command `php artisan make:controller <Controller Name> ` to properly create a controller

Comment: Supply an argument for your controller; e.g: `php artisan make:controller MyController`; are you doing in this format ?

Comment: Check your routes/web.php file, you have something wrong in it that prevent the command from running, doing `php artisan` should also fail

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a combination of suggested places to check, based on the provided error response you pasted above:

1. First, check your `web.php` or `api.php` in `routes` folder and verify if you have unexpected additional parameters. For example, `Route::post('/foo/{hello}/bar/{world}', [FallbackController::class, 'testFunction']);` and we see that you'll next have to declared `$hello` and `$world` shortly.
2. Next, does your function looks like this? (following the example from #1) Such as `public function testFunction($hello, $world, Request $request)`.
3. Third, based on the HTTP method used, and for the route defined using `FallbackController`, were you able to simplify it to test your HTTP method with the route again? For this, I still assume it is a route in `api.php` correct?

Lastly, if any of above fails to help, I recommend implementing a simple route to test with (GET or POST) first. This will help you trace back what you missed.

Using Docker (and a fresh Laravel 9) to help fill in other clues, like incorrect `php` or `composer` version and more - using a template like this might help, https://github.com/k90mirzaei/laravel9-docker.

Please note, I am answering based on the provided error first. Hope my checklist above helps.